# RAR3 hashing algorithm

Tags: hash, rar, rainbowtable

I came accross a hash that starts as follows, which I'm trying to reverse: `$rar3$*1*`

However, I can't seem to find a rainbow table for the rar3 hashing algorithm.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rainbow tables won't work:
[RAR passwords, why don't rainbow tables work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817941/rar-passwords-why-dont-rainbow-tables-work)

**$RAR3$*0***, which is RAR with opening-password, is supported by [Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes). [[2](https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-5334.html)]

It is created with the -hp option: [[3](http://blog.zorinaq.com/brute-forcing-rar-archives-encrypted-with-the-hp-option/)]

> **-hp option**, which encrypts the internal block headers that contain file metadata, as well as the content of the files
>
> **-p option**, which encrypts only the content of the files in the archive, while file metadata (filenames...) are not encrypted

**$RAR3$*1***, which is created with -p, is not supported by Hashcat. You can try [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) to crack it instead. [[5](https://superuser.com/questions/1175016/why-wont-hashcat-accept-this-rar3-hash)][[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113342/using-hashcat-with-a-rar-file)]

[cRARk](http://crark.net/) freeware utility to crack RAR password

Comment: hashcat supports *$RAR3$1* https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/pull/2542